# CouchDB Document Update Handlers: Javascript

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am trying to create a generic document update handler.

I am using:

```
function(doc, req) {var field = req.query.field;  var value = 
req.query.value; var message = 'set '+field+' to '+value;  doc[field] = 
value; return [doc, message];  }
```

This works ok with simple json but not with a nested object such as

```
"abc":{"ax":"one", "by":"two" ...}
```

my curl command is:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/db/_design/updatehandler/_update/inplace/id?field=abc.ax&value=three'
```

The result is a new field is created and the existing abc:{ax:one} is left 
untouched.

With a simpler example:

if I have: `"xyz":"five"`

```
curl -X PUT 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/db/_design/updatehandler/_update/inplace/id?field=xyz&value=ten'
```

... works correctly.

I have not yet tried the generic process on `"pqr":[s, t, u]` yet but I guess 
this may require a different design modification as well.

Ideally one wants something that works in at least the abovementioned three 
cases if possible, as long as it is not too complex for it not to be worth 
the effort.

Could someone possibly kindly help here or refer me to some javascript examples please.

Many thanks.

John

Answer (score 0):

```js
function (doc, req) {
    function merge(nDoc,oDoc ) {
        for (var f in nDoc) {
            var tmpNewDoc = nDoc[f],
                tmpDoc = oDoc[f];
            var type = typeof(tmpNewDoc);
            if (type === 'object' && tmpNewDoc.length === undefined && tmpDoc !== undefined) merge(tmpNewDoc, tmpDoc);
            else oDoc[f] = tmpNewDoc;
        }
    }
 
    if (!doc) {
  return [null, toJSON({
   error: 'not_found',
   reason: 'No document were found with the specified ID or an incorrect method was used.'
  })];
 }
 
 try {
  var newDoc = JSON.parse(req.body);
  merge(newDoc, doc);
 }
 
 catch (e) {
  return [null, ToJSON({
   error: 'bad_request',
   reason: 'Invalid json or processing error'
  })];
 }
 
    return [doc, toJSON({
        doc: doc,
        ok: true
    })];
}"
  }
```

Simply pass the new document to this handler. It will merge the new values to it (warning, the arrays will be overwrite). If you also want to merge array, you can either use a third party library or build your own recursive merge function.

Comment: Thank you @Alexis. In this case you have proposed, what would the curl POST command look like?

Comment: See [this documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/ddoc/render.html#post--db-_design-ddoc-_update-func)

Comment: Hi @Alexis. Thank you for that. Sorry to hassle you. I get the following error when running the update: `{"error":"render_error","reason":"function raised error: (new TypeError(\"Object.assign is not a function\"` Does this indicate anything I am doing incorrectly. Sorry again.

Comment: Seems like this function is not available. I added a custom implementation of the merge

Comment: Sorry @Alexis this is too difficult for me to work through. Also, CouchDB 2.0.0 won't allow me to save the above code. Many thanks for your help. I appreciate it.